# Confidence interval of transformed Fitted Model

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, nonlinear

I have a `FitteddModel` coming from a `NonlinearModelFit` this model depends on two parameters x1 and x2. I want to obtain the values of x2 at which the output of the model is 0.5, for a long list of x1.I do this in the following way:

```
Table[FindRoot[model[x, y] == 0.5, {y, 1}], {x, -50, 20}]
```

So I can obtain a graph like this:

[image: model output]

The problem now is trying to add the errors on every point or a confidence band in the graph. I'm completely clueless about how to do it.

Hope you can help.

Here is the model I'm trying to fit:

```
K1[ca_] := (10^LogKd)/( (10^(ca))^n)
Kv[v_] := E^(2.8 (v + 18)/25.7)
Po[v_, ca_] := (K1[ca]*Kv[v])/(1 + K1[ca] + (K1[ca]*Kv[v]))
inh[v_, ca_] := Po[v, ca]/Po[v, -5]    
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, inh[x1, x2], {LogKd, n}, {x1, x2}]
```

The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxzVmMJwPgcNS3RwazhtSHRHUlE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just to clarify:  You want confidence intervals for `y` in `Solve[inh[x,y]==0.5,y]` given `x` accounting for the uncertainties in the estimates of `LogKd` and `n` from the nonlinear regression?

Comment: @JimBaldwin Yep, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer gives how to obtain approximate confidence intervals for `y` in `Solve[inh[x,y]==0.5,y]` given `x` and accounting for the uncertainties in the estimates of `LogKd` and `n` from the nonlinear regression using the Delta Method.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method and/or

```
Bishop, Y.M. M., Fienberg, S.E. and Holland, P.W. (1975). 
    Discrete Multivariate Analysis: Theory and Practice. M.I.T. Press, Cambridge, MA.
```

First perform the regression and obtain estimates of the coefficients and the covariance matrix:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, inh[x1, x2], {LogKd, n}, {x1, x2}]
sol = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
cov = nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]
```

Now solve for `y` in terms of `x`:

```
f[x_] := y /. Solve[inh[x, y] == 0.5, y][[1]]
```

Take the partial derivative with respect to both regression parameters:

```
fpartial = D[f[x], {{LogKd, n}}]
```

The approximate variance of `y` given `x` is given by

```
yVar = fpartial.cov.fpartial /. sol
```

Now plot the prediction and the associated approximate 95% confidence bands:

```
Plot[{f[x], f[x] + 1.96 yVar^0.5, f[x] - 1.96 yVar^0.5} /. sol, {x, -50, 20}]
```

[image: Predictions and confidence bands]

Comment: +1, just want to say how much I enjoy your answers re: prob/stats in MMA - always interesting, educational, and useful.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Could you please add some reference about the methodology? Thanks!

Comment: Added two references.  A Google search for Delta Method brings up many others.

Comment: @ciao Thanks!  I've learned much more from this site than I've given back in answers so it works out great for me.